# Understanding Fibonacci Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to show that $$F^2_{k+1} - F^2_k = F_{k-1} * F_{k+2}  ∀ ≥1$$  where $$F_k = F_{k-1}  + F_{k-2}$$  with $$F_0 = F_1 = 1$$

Let P(n) = $$F^2_{k+1} - F^2_k = F_{k-1} * F_{k+2}$$

Basic Step: is P(1) true?

$$(F^2_2 - F^2_1) = 3 = 3 = (F_0 * F_3)$$ Is true because $$LHS = RHS$$

Assume that $$F^2_{k+1} - F^2_k = F_{k-1} * F_{k+2}$$  is true, then we want to show that P(k+1) is also true:

$$F^2_{k+2} - F^2_{k+1}  = (F_{k+2} – F_{k+1})(F_{k+2} + F_{k+1})$$

$$= F_k * F_{k+3}$$

Thus, P(k) <----> P(k+1) ?

Comment: You don't need induction! This follows directly from the recurence relation: $F_{k+1}^2 = (F_{k}+F_{k-1})^2$.

Comment: How did you factor $F^2_{k+1}$

Comment: What I wrote is the (square of the) definition of $F_{k+1}$. Expand the right hand side to get $F_{k+1}^2 = F_k^2 + F_{k-1}([F_k + F_{k-1}] + F_k)$. Now we are almost there, just use the recurence relation two more times on the terms in the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

No induction needed: $F_{k+1}^2-F_k^2=(F_{k+1}-F_k)(F_{k+1}+F_k)=F_{k-1}\cdot F_{k+2}$

Comment: How does $(F_{k+1}-F_k)(F_{k+1}+F_k)=F_{k-1}\cdot F_{k+2}$

Comment: From the Fibonacci recursion, $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$.  For instance $F_9-F_8=F_7$ and $F_9+F_8=F_{10}$

Comment: Okay, finally had the 'aaaha' moment. Thanks

Comment: I updated my post, is my proof by MI sound?

Answer (score 3):

$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$$

Set $n=k,k+1$  one by one.

Can you see the way, now?

Comment: no, can you elaborate please

Comment: @ChetSteadman,  $n=k\implies F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_k\iff F_{k+2}-F_{k+1}=F_k$  and  $n=k+1\implies F_{(k+1)+2}=F_{(k+1)+1}+F_{(k+1)}$